# Julia convert number to string in scientific notation

Tags: string, type-conversion, julia

Does Julia have a way to convert a number to scientific notation in the string type?

For instance:

300 becomes "3.00E+02"
    or 
0.0045 becomes "4.5E-03"
    or 
3.14159 becomes "3.14159E+00"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the standard library [`Printf`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Printf/) for this.

```
julia> using Printf
julia> @printf "%.2E" 300
3.00E+02
```

if you don't want to print, but rather convert to an appropriately formatted string, you can do

```
julia> using Printf
julia> str = @sprintf "%.2E" 300
"3.00E+02"
```